# Creating array of JSON objects from multiple columns

Tags: arrays, postgresql, aggregate-functions, jsonb, postgres-9.6

I have the following dataset here

| id | key | category | avg_time_1 | avg_time_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 | 10 | 20 |
| 2 | 1 | 20 | 30 | 40 |
| 3 | 2 | 10 | 10 | 50 |
| 4 | 2 | 20 | 60 | 70 |

[Sqlfiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/70f9a/1)

I want to create a query that the result will be as follow:

| key | avg_time_1 | avg_time_1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [{ "category": 10, "avg_time": 10},{ "category": 20, "avg_time": 20 }] | [{"category": 10, "avg_time": 20}, {"category": 20, "avg_time": 40}] |
| 2 | [{ "category": 10, "avg_time": 10},{ "category": 20, "avg_time": 60}] | [{"category": 10, "avg_time": 50}, {"category": 20, "avg_time": 70}] |

The idea is just to re-present the values cols `avg_time_1` and `avg_time_2` in a different way, as jsonb values.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `jsonb_build_object()` to build prime objects and `jsonb_agg()` to aggregate them into a json array:

```
select 
    key, 
    jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('category', category, 'avg_time', avg_time_1)) as avg_time_1,
    jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('category', category, 'avg_time', avg_time_2)) as avg_time_2
from data_to_agg_json
group by key

 key |                              avg_time_1                              |                              avg_time_2                              
-----+----------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------
   1 | [{"avg_time": 10, "category": 10}, {"avg_time": 30, "category": 20}] | [{"avg_time": 20, "category": 10}, {"avg_time": 40, "category": 20}]
   2 | [{"avg_time": 10, "category": 10}, {"avg_time": 60, "category": 20}] | [{"avg_time": 50, "category": 10}, {"avg_time": 70, "category": 20}]
(2 rows)
```

[Db<>Fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=e5235f017bfeacbd44d15a1d687281f0)